# Multiple KeyEvents?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, overriding, keyevent

Hi I have a problem with my Android app. I use a boolean method to change the function of the back button to make a layout change. As shown in the code if I use a if- statement and if these things are true, the layout changes. The problem is I have more than one point with different situations where I would like to modify the function of the button. But if I copy the function and change the name eclipse wants to remove the @ override, and then the method no longer works.

So now the question is: How can I create multiple KeyEvents?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && lengthisopen == true){

        lengthisopen = false;
        setContentView(R.layout.length);
        return true;
    } 
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}


public boolean onKeyDown2(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && lengthisopen == true){

        lengthisopen = false;
        setContentView(R.layout.length);
        return true;
    } 
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

Comment: Both your methods are the same. Why do you need 2 of them ?

Comment: oh sry the second method should be R.layout.time

Answer (score 0):

`onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` is a method available is `Activity`, So you can override it. But `onKeyDown2()` is not a super class's method. So you can't override it from any of the super classes. That's why it said you to remove `@override`.

If you want to create multiple key events then you should go to only

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && lengthisopen == true){

        lengthisopen = false;
        setContentView(R.layout.length);
        return true;
    } 
    else if(condition){
         // next code
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i wantet, but if i try this in the virtual device it sais "TL Calc unfortunately stopped" an crashes...